# Parsing different value types in Java for an EventBus

Tags: java, parsing, architecture, event-handling

I am receiving simple data across a network, name/value pairs in text. I need to write a process to take  those pairs, chop them up and send them to a different area - via an event bus - to be processed. Each name represents a different data "type" or transformational operation that I will have to do on the value part of the string.

On the surface this is pretty straightforward, but I am looking for a simple, "correct" architecture to do this such that I can transform 300 different kinds of values. Here is a simple example:

input:

```
9,19.0,31,0.00,34,0.379579,37,1.319952,55,0.03,66,0.00,81,1.558965,82,1.578690,92,0.03,99,24.57,100,-8144.29,101,0.13,105,2.999,106,148.3,108,-155.8,111,4.263,112,155.0,113,-170.0,167,10.60,205,1.558965,231,-0.040,232,-93.8,237,75.0,238,0.100
```

Really means:

```
9,19.0

31,0.00

34,0.379579
```

etc...

In the case of the "34" event, I have to convert that number to a different value for display to the user. So each event type can, potentially, have a different conversion process. In reality, I think that there might be groups of conversion processes (like 12) across all 300 event types.

Here are my questions.

1. How do I handle all of the conversion types? Is this like the sort algorithm or a comparator that you can inject into a parser?
2. How can I be efficient in terms of object creation and GC? These pairs are coming off of a network and I do not want to just shed GC-able objects (I am on Android).
3. Should I map the various types to an Events that go on a bus and only have consumers sign up for the events they are interested in, or do I send a generic event to every consumer and have them decide each time (I am thinking the former, but also dreading the boilerplate).

Any general thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up letting the compiler worry about it for me. I have a HUGE switch statement with many, many cases for each specific type of conversion.

I have also combed through the code and pulled out object declarations for things that I will be reusing. I make sure that they are declared above the function that wants to use them, then I set them early in the function to whatever value they need to be.

I have a single event type, for the network data I am collecting. I let each receiver decide if it cares about that event. This just eliminated a ton of boilerplate code that would have to be written to have a factory create each different event type.